# Eclipse won't update or install software

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, subversive

I recently installed subversion on my machine. So I decided to get Subversive for eclipse so that I could check my Android projects in. The problem is, it will get to a certain percentage, say 49%, and just sit there. I give it hours and hours of time and it doesn't move. I figured I'd try to update Eclipse to see if that would help, but I can't even update it. The exact same thing happens. I've tried running it as administrator, changing network settings, but no luck. Any help is greatly appreciated on this.

Here's where the Subversive install is currently stuck at:

[image]

Comment: This happens to me all the time, I end up re-installing Eclipse, and still half the time it doesn't help. (In other words you could try re-installing.)

Comment: I was thinking of resorting to that. I just have it set up exactly the way I want for android, so I'm really hesitant to do that.

Comment: Under current software make sure that the current version of eclipse is in that list, so that it actually will update (Indigo I believe) you may want to check out subclipse instead, I use that no problem

Comment: Where do I find current software?